# how to get selected UISwitch tag from UITableView sections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

How to get a UISwitch tag from multiple sections. I have 3 sections, user can change switch status. Based on that I want to get that switch tag and section index.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please add more information and some code.

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 0):

You can set previously

```
switch.accessibilityValue = "\(indexPath.section)"
```

and get back

```
let section = Int(cell.accessibilityValue ?? "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50)];
   UISwitch *onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
   [onoff addTarget: self action: @selector(flip:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   onoff.tag = section;
   [view addSubview: onoff];
}
- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender 
{ 
   if(sender.tag == 0)
    {
      //Do whatever you want to do.
    }
    else if(sender.tag == 1){
      //You can add as many as you want.
    }
}
```

One more thing you need to know about header in the table view that to override header height. You can do it like this :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, it's worked for me....

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)mySwitch.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [_deviceRulesTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"toggle section %ld rowID %ld", (long)indexpath.section, (long)indexpath.row);

if (indexpath.section == 1) {
}
```